# Emulator Settings Menu doesn't work

Tags: android, settings, emulation

Using the level 11/3.0 emulator, the 'Settings' menu doesn't work. Click on any item eg. 'Sound' or 'Screen' and nothing happens beyond the momentary high-lighting of the item.

In eclipse, a logcat entry appears

INFO/ActivityManager(73): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings (has extras) } from pid 375

and nothing else.

What's going on here??? I only want to change the language settings from the default Chinese!

update: I've got the screen set to a normal size(320x480) instead of the default(and only option) WXGA. Works fine if I use the WXGA setting - new windows open etc. Is ver 3.0 only for tablets? I thought the system was supposed to gracefully accommodate different-sized screens. I only installed it because ver 2.3 doesn't do javascript bridge or location spoofing.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

Make sure you have your "Device ram size" setting for this AVD set high. It will default to 256, but I recommend 1024 (MB) if you can spare it. You can adjust this via the SDK and AVD Manager.

Comment: Thanks Commonsware - I'll do that - maybe that explains why its so slow to boot on WXGA setting - see my edit to the original question.

Comment: @Geoff: "Is ver 3.0 only for tablets? " -- yes. "I thought the system was supposed to gracefully accommodate different-sized screens." -- Android 3.0 will not be deployed on smaller screen sizes. The expectation is the next version of Android (Ice Cream Sandwich, presumably Android 3.1) will introduce Honeycomb-style UIs to phones and will work across phones and tablets. "I only installed it because ver 2.3 doesn't do javascript bridge or location spoofing." -- hopefully you also installed it to test your app on a tablet-sized screen.

Comment: @Geoff: "I've got the screen set to a normal size(320x480) instead of the default(and only option) WXGA. " -- please don't do that.